# Find and replace text in label jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've label for ex. : `<label id="labelId" class="control-label col-lg-4">Some text ()</label>`, how can i insert text in the middle of brakets and after clear it?

I've tried :

```
$('#labelId').replace("()", "(new)");
```

But that is not work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've to get the text using `text()` replace it using `replace()` then set the replaced text back to the label.

**jQuery solution :**

```
var label_text = $('#labelId').text(); //Get the text
$('#labelId').text( label_text.replace("()", "(new)") ); //Replace and set the text back
```

**Pure js solution :**

```
var label_text = document.getElementById('labelId').innerText; //Get the text
document.getElementById('labelId').innerText = label_text.replace("()", "(new)"); //Replace and set the text back
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  var label_text = $('#labelId').text();

  $('#labelId').text( label_text.replace("()", "(new)") );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="labelId" class="control-label col-lg-4">Some text ()</label>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

```js
$('#labelId').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace("()", "(new)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="labelId" class="control-label col-lg-4">Some text ()</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#labelId").text($("#labelId").text().replace("()","(test)"));
})
```

```html
<label id="labelId" class="control-label col-lg-4">Some text ()</label>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```